# Ninject Console App - DebugException does not have an implementation?

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

just fired up a new console app project. I've added Ninject, Ninject.Extensions.Logging, Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net

I've setup ninject like so:

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new WorkerNinjectModule()))
{
    var queueProcessor = kernel.Get<QueueProcessor>();
    queueProcessor.ProcessQueue(processFromShopify);
}
```

and am getting a type load exception:

'DebugException' in type 'Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4net.Infrastructure.Log4NetLogger' from assembly 'Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' does not have an implementation.

just wondering if anyone knew how to fix this? or is log4net something you shouldn't be using in a console app..

Comment: Using log4net for console apps is fine.  Maybe you get get some more help by providing an app.config file, line number of the exception and complete exception stack, including (especially) any inner exceptions that might have occurred.